# In Orchard CMS, what model binds to the layout view?

Tags: orchardcms

The Orchard CMS has an Area called TheThemeMachine. It has a view file called Layout.cshtml. My understanding is that views bind to models, and that models are defined as classes. The following code snippet, taken from the Layout.cshtml file, references a model.

```
@Zone(Model.BeforeContent)
```

Where is the class that represents the model? Where is the property called BeforeContent? I have searched the entire solution for the BeforeContent property and have not found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Orchard, the model for most views is a dynamic object called a shape. It's dynamic, so what class implements the shape/model is irrelevant. In the case of Layout.cshtml, the model is a shape called Layout. Model.BeforeContent is another shape, that is the model for the zone called BeforeContent. See http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes for more info.